# How to enable paging in datatable for fixed column

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have implemented datatable fixed header using,

```
new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(table,{
     paging: true
});
```

It's working fine but paging is disabled that all 11000 rows in my table is getting loaded at a time and system is getting hung. Can any one suggest me how could I enable pagination for this?

Comment: https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/server-side-processing.html found an example in the docs which might help?

Comment: Thanks @Paul for the response.